# How to trigger RTK query when we have error?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

hi how can I trigger again RTK query after it fails to fetch data for first time for example after  error with status code 500?

Comment: You can use `refetch`. Assuming you use the normal query hook. Since you don't provide any code, it's hard to help you.

Comment: @phry is there a way to refetch automatically after specific error ? each of them trigger again if there is for example a error with status code 5000 just one time more?

Comment: in that case you would wrap the baseQuery - there are some examples for that in the docs, for example the authentication examples